# Best way to let Admin create User in ASP MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-identity

In Visual Studio 2013 i have created a MVC project with Individual Account (ASP Net Identity 2.X).

So at the url Account/Register an (anonymous) user can sign up.

Now i want that an admin user can also create an user (and in the view there are some additional fields respect to the register view).

What's the best way to accomplish this?
I use the same route and view (Account/Register) but i show some field in the view according to the role of the user? Or i create another route/controller/view only for admin?

Comment: If the two `Models` will be different create two separate routes easier to maintain in the long run. Also easier to apply security to the new route

Answer (score 1):

I think best ways is:

> Create AdminControoler in ASP MVC or WebApi (if any) and there write
>   all method for user with role admin.

Like:

```
 [Authorize(Roles = "ADMIN")]
    public class AdminController : ApiController
{

  [HttpPost]
    public void CreateUser(UserViewModel model)
    {
        ... your logic
    }
}
```

This is best practice because if you will need add a few new methods for user-admin only, you will add in this controller